# Scala and mockito to test twilio MessageFactory.create() method

Tags: scala, testing, mocking, mockito

I'd like to test our Twilio integration using some simple dependency injection and mocking. It seems to me the easiest method would be to use `mockito` to intercept the following message `create` call:

```
val messageFactory: MessageFactory = smsProvider.getAccount().getMessageFactory()
val message: Message = messageFactory.create(params)
```

Ideally I'd like to stub out the `create` call so that I can validate that it was called, and that the parameters are correct.

I'm new to Mockito though, and trying to piece together how to use it in Scala (and if this kind of testing is even possible). Most examples I've found are in Java, etc., and don't translate well to Scala.

Answer (score 2):

You can use mockito with Scala. Add mockito to your library dependencies (e.g., using SBT something like `libraryDependencies += "org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "1.8.5" % "test"`) and you're set.

If you're using Scalatest, there's also `MockitoSugar` that you can mix in as a trait or import statically, giving you the syntactic sugar `mock[ClassToMock]` instead of mockito's `mock(classOf[ClassToMock])`.

Mockito allows you to pass a mock-object as external dependency to your "unit under test" and assert that a certain method is called. In your case, the external dependency should either be `messageFactory` or `smsProvider`. However, the latter requires you to pass a stub for `smsProvider` to return a mock for `MessageFactory`.

Your code could look as follows:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.verify
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar

// Your Test
class MessageCreatorTest extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

  val messageCreator = new MessageCreator

  "createMessage" should "create a new message" in {
    val factory = mock[MessageFactory]

    messageCreator.createMessage(factory)

    verify(factory).create(any[List[String]])
  }
}

// Your Unit Under Test
class MessageCreator {
  def createMessage(messageFactory: MessageFactory): Unit ={
    messageFactory.create(List("Foo", "Bar"))
  }
}

// The external dependency of your Unit Under Test
trait MessageFactory {
  def create(params: List[String]) = new Message("Hello")
}

// A plain value
case class Message(message: String)
```

However, if your unit under test depends on `smsFactory`, you'll notice that setting up the test becomes more of a burden:

```
import org.mockito.Mockito.{when, verify}
import org.mockito.Matchers.any
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.mock.MockitoSugar

class MessageCreatorTest extends FlatSpec with MockitoSugar {

  val messageCreator = new MessageCreator

  "createMessage" should "create a new message" in {
    val factory = mock[MessageFactory]
    val account = mock[Account]
    val smsProvider = mock[SmsProvider]
    when(smsProvider.getAccount).thenReturn(account)
    when(account.getMessageFactory).thenReturn(factory)

    messageCreator.createMessage(smsProvider)

    verify(factory).create(any[List[String]])
  }
}

class MessageCreator {
  def createMessage(smsProvider: SmsProvider): Unit = {
    val messageFactory = smsProvider.getAccount.getMessageFactory
    messageFactory.create(List("Foo", "Bar"))
  }
}

trait MessageFactory {
  def create(params: List[String]) = new Message("Hello")
}

case class Message(message: String)

trait SmsProvider {
  def getAccount: Account
}

trait Account {
  def getMessageFactory: MessageFactory
}
```

In that case however, the test tells you that you're violating the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Comment: You can also use specs2 trait `Mockito` while using scalatest https://code.google.com/p/specs/wiki/UsingMockito I think that syntax `smsProvider.getAccount returns account` is much cooler that the original.

Comment: I am using specs2. Also, in regard to the Law of Demeter: Yes. But. I could simply mock my own Messenger object (which uses the Twilio library). However, I really, really want to test that the correct parameters have been passed to Twilio, so I'm struggling with a solution that meets that need and violates as few injection (LoD) principles as possible...

Comment: @kulu-limpa that looks great – will give it a try tomorrow and offer any feedback from a specs2 perspective... thank you!